# Linq's let statement sets references to null

Tags: c#, linq

A certain constellation of objects containing `SortedList`s have the references to those lists set to `null` when using a `let` in Linq queries.

Here is a minimum working example. Most of it is just a set-up of things to make sure it reflects the context I’m working in; the important part is at the very last line, which throws a `NullReferenceException` since `testList["1"].Elements` is `null`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TypecastTest {

  public abstract class ComplexBase { }

  public abstract class ComplexClass : ComplexBase {
    internal SortedList<string, ComplexElement> Elements { get; set; }
  }

  public abstract class ComplexElement : ComplexBase { }

  public class ComplexClassA : ComplexClass {
    internal new SortedList<string, ComplexElementA> Elements { get; set; }

    public ComplexClassA() {
      Elements = new SortedList<string, ComplexElementA>();
    }
  }

  public class ComplexElementA : ComplexElement { }

  public class ComplexClassB : ComplexClass {
    internal new SortedList<string, ComplexElementB> Elements { get; set; }

    public ComplexClassB() {
      Elements = new SortedList<string, ComplexElementB>();
    }
  }

  public class ComplexElementB : ComplexElement { }

  public class TheBigCollection {
    internal SortedList<string, ComplexClass> Classes { get; set; }

    public TheBigCollection() {
      Classes = new SortedList<string, ComplexClass>();
    }
  }

  class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      ComplexClassA ccA1 = new ComplexClassA();
      ComplexElementA ceA1a = new ComplexElementA();
      ComplexElementA ceA1b = new ComplexElementA();
      ccA1.Elements.Add("A1a", ceA1a);
      ccA1.Elements.Add("A1b", ceA1b);

      ComplexClassA ccA2 = new ComplexClassA();
      ComplexElementA ceA2a = new ComplexElementA();
      ComplexElementA ceA2b = new ComplexElementA();
      ccA2.Elements.Add("A2a", ceA2a);
      ccA2.Elements.Add("A2b", ceA2b);

      ComplexClassB ccB1 = new ComplexClassB();
      ComplexElementB ceB1a = new ComplexElementB();
      ComplexElementB ceB1b = new ComplexElementB();
      ccB1.Elements.Add("B1a", ceB1a);
      ccB1.Elements.Add("B1b", ceB1b);

      ComplexClassB ccB2 = new ComplexClassB();
      ComplexElementB ceB2a = new ComplexElementB();
      ComplexElementB ceB2b = new ComplexElementB();
      ccB2.Elements.Add("B2a", ceB2a);
      ccB2.Elements.Add("B2b", ceB2b);

      TheBigCollection tbc = new TheBigCollection();
      tbc.Classes.Add("1", ccA1);
      tbc.Classes.Add("2", ccA2);
      tbc.Classes.Add("3", ccB1);
      tbc.Classes.Add("4", ccB2);

      var query = from kvp in tbc.Classes
                  let tmp = new {
                    tmpKey = kvp.Key,
                    tmpValue = kvp.Value
                  }
                  select tmp;
      Dictionary<string, ComplexClass> testDictionary = query.ToDictionary(x => x.tmpKey, x => x.tmpValue);
      SortedList<string, ComplexClass> testList = new SortedList<string, ComplexClass>(testDictionary);
      int test = testList["1"].Elements.Count;
    }
  }
}
```

Why is this `null`? What happens within the generation of an anonymous object in `let` that prevents the reference to be copied correctly?

Comment: The problem arises way before that; I tried your code, and `Elements` is already null for every item in `tbc`

Comment: Your `ComplexClassA` hides the `Elements` in the base class `ComplexClass`.  The `Elements` in `ComplexClass` is `null` and your dictionary is referring to `ComplexClass`, so it sees the `Elements` that is `null`.  This is why you should avoid designs that use `new` instead of `virtual` and `override`.  If you do `((ComplexClassA)testList["1"]).Elements.Count` it would work as this forces it to see the `Elements` of the `ComplexClassA` which is not `null`.

Comment: ^ this - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173153.aspx

Comment: Thanks, @juharr. I see that this might be one of the reasons why hiding is discouraged. On the other hand, I can’t use `override` instead of `new`, since this does not allow for changing the `SortedList`s as I do above. However, in order to allow for the definition of generic methods on `ComplexClass`es, I see no way around defining the list inside `ComplexClass` and hiding it. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Informagic Basically it looks like you need to use generics.  So `ComplexClass<T> : ComplexBase where T : ComplexElement` and then `SortedList<string, T> Elements {get;set;}` and finally `ComplexClassA : ComplexClass<ComplexElementA>` and you don't have to define `Elements` again.  Though you'll need a co-variant interface for `TheBigColleciton` to work, but I don't really have room here to get into that.  So give that a try and if you hit more problems post a new question.

Comment: @juharr The problem I see here is that, with a covariance interface (such as using `IEnumerable`), I'd have an immutable list to which I could not add new elements. In particular, I couldn't add elements of different derived types. I think I might post this as a new question.

Comment: @juharr I've posted a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38629989/covariance-for-classes-with-list-members-in-c-sharp/38631643#38631643). Trouble with casting prevails, though.