# Covariance for classes with list members in C#

Tags: c#, list, generics, covariance

Consider a class hierarchy that looks as below. In essence, there is an abstract `ComplexBase` with some fields that are common to all classes. Then there is a `ComplexClass` derived from `ComplexBase` that, among other things, holds a collection of `ComplexElement`s also derived from `ComplexBase`.

```
public abstract class ComplexBase {
  internal abstract string Identifier { get; }
}

public abstract class ComplexClass<T> : ComplexBase where T : ComplexElement {
  internal SortedList<string, T> Elements { get; set; }
}

public abstract class ComplexElement : ComplexBase { }
```

Implementations of the abstract classes are `ComplexClassA` and `ComplexClassB`. The `ComplexElement` collection of the former only contains instances of `ComplexElementA` and of the latter only `ComplexElementB`.

```
public class ComplexClassA : ComplexClass<ComplexElementA> {
  public ComplexClassA() {
    Elements = new SortedList<string, ComplexElementA>();
  }
}

public class ComplexElementA : ComplexElement { }

public class ComplexClassB : ComplexClass<ComplexElementB> {
  public ComplexClassB() {
    Elements = new SortedList<string, ComplexElementB>();
  }
}

public class ComplexElementB : ComplexElement { }
```

What I am struggling to understand is how to define a new class `TheBigCollection` holding various fields and methods, plus a collection of instances of both `ComplexClassA` and `ComplexClassB`. A non-working version might look like

```
public class TheBigCollection {
  internal SortedList<string, ComplexClass> Classes { get; set; }

  public TheBigCollection() {
    Classes = new SortedList<string, ComplexClass>();
  }

  public void Add(string name, ComplexClass element) {
    Classes.Add(name, element);
  }
}
```

Of course this doesn't compile since `ComplexClass` is defined with a generic type.

My [previous attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38615325/linqs-let-statement-sets-references-to-null) was to use a concept of hiding the lists, but it turns out that this prevents me from accessing the lists of `ComplexElements` in instances of `ComplexClassA` or `ComplexClassB` that I retrieve from the list in `TheBigCollection`.

I learnt from my previous post that covariance could solve the problem, but I fail to understand how using `IEnumerable`—which is immutable—can be used to add new elements tho `TheBigCollection`'s list of classes.

Comment: Did you consider creating an intermediate class ComplexClassBase : ComplexBase and inheriting ComplexClass<T> from ComplexClassBase?

Comment: @michauzo Yes, I did, very much in the line of the answer to [this post](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/660308-list-of-generic-objects/). The problem that arises with this solution is that I can't iterate over the list `Classes` and access, for instance, each item's `Elements.Count` property anymore without a proper cast.

Comment: in the intermediate class (or interface) you could put property SortedList<string, ComplexElement> Elements { get; set; } and then implement it in ComplexClass using specialized type.

Comment: Unfortunately, this means that `Elements` in the intermediate class would be `null` for any implementation of `ComplexClass`. The specialized type would hide the more general property `SortedList<string, ComplexElement>` and any item in the `Classes` list of `TheBigCollection` would show `Elements` as `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following and it works fine.

```
internal interface IComplexClass
{
    IDictionary<string, ComplexElement> Elements { get; }
}

public abstract class ComplexClass<T> : ComplexBase, IComplexClass where T : ComplexElement
{
    internal SortedList<string, T> Elements { get; set; }

    IDictionary<string, ComplexElement> IComplexClass.Elements
    {
        get { return (IDictionary<string, ComplexElement>)Elements; }
    }
}
```

Now you could use IComplexClass in TheBigCollection.

Comment: This seems nice—I didn’t know that one could overwrite the getter of the base class by referring to it using the class name—but there is a problem here, too. Imagine that I have a Linq query on the member `Classes` of an instance of `TheBigColletcion`. When accessing `Elements` of an item of the query result at run time, the getter throws a `System.InvalidCastException` since it tries to cast a `SortedList` with, e.g., `ComplexClassA`s to an `IDictionary` with `ComplexClass`es.

Comment: A getter that does give access as planned and avoids the `System.InvalidCastException` is one that puts the cast inside the `KeyValuePair` by using `get { return Elements.ToDictionary(el => el.Key, el => (ComplexElement)el.Value); }`. Astonishing.

Comment: Indeed. Your solution is not very elegant but it works and I don't see any better one so far.